# Extract wave data from wave form image using HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, html5-audio

I've seen people try to extract the data from a wave form image using php but can this or has anyone ver achieved it using HTML5 canvas?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ImageData to examine each row, column or pixel.  You'll need to use:

`var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)`

The image data is an array of r, g, b, and a pixel values so the first pixel on the canvas is at indices 0(r), 1(g), 2(b) and 3(a).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Marching Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares)  algorithm to fetch a set of points along the image representing the wave.

The excellent d3 library has a [plug-in](https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/tree/master/geom/contour) that implements Marching Squares.

The plugin can be used separately outside d3 to get your wave contour point set.

The plugin code is liberally licensed (see copyright notice below).

```
(function() {

d3.geom.contour = function(grid, start) {
  var s = start || d3_geom_contourStart(grid), // starting point
      c = [],    // contour polygon
      x = s[0],  // current x position
      y = s[1],  // current y position
      dx = 0,    // next x direction
      dy = 0,    // next y direction
      pdx = NaN, // previous x direction
      pdy = NaN, // previous y direction
      i = 0;

  do {
    // determine marching squares index
    i = 0;
    if (grid(x-1, y-1)) i += 1;
    if (grid(x,   y-1)) i += 2;
    if (grid(x-1, y  )) i += 4;
    if (grid(x,   y  )) i += 8;

    // determine next direction
    if (i === 6) {
      dx = pdy === -1 ? -1 : 1;
      dy = 0;
    } else if (i === 9) {
      dx = 0;
      dy = pdx === 1 ? -1 : 1;
    } else {
      dx = d3_geom_contourDx[i];
      dy = d3_geom_contourDy[i];
    }

    // update contour polygon
    if (dx != pdx && dy != pdy) {
      c.push([x, y]);
      pdx = dx;
      pdy = dy;
    }

    x += dx;
    y += dy;
  } while (s[0] != x || s[1] != y);

  return c;
};

// lookup tables for marching directions
var d3_geom_contourDx = [1, 0, 1, 1,-1, 0,-1, 1,0, 0,0,0,-1, 0,-1,NaN],
    d3_geom_contourDy = [0,-1, 0, 0, 0,-1, 0, 0,1,-1,1,1, 0,-1, 0,NaN];

function d3_geom_contourStart(grid) {
  var x = 0,
      y = 0;

  // search for a starting point; begin at origin
  // and proceed along outward-expanding diagonals
  while (true) {
    if (grid(x,y)) {
      return [x,y];
    }
    if (x === 0) {
      x = y + 1;
      y = 0;
    } else {
      x = x - 1;
      y = y + 1;
    }
  }
}

})();
```

---

> Copyright (c) 2012-2014, Michael Bostock All rights reserved.
>
> Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
>   modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are
>   met:
>
> - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this   list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
> - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,   this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
>     documentation   and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
> - The name Michael Bostock may not be used to endorse or promote products   derived from this software without specific prior written
>     permission.
>
> THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
>   "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
>   LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
>   A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL MICHAEL BOSTOCK
>   BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR
>   CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF
>   SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR
>   BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY,
>   WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE
>   OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN
>   IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.